# 3 State Checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Microsoft Word 2013 and inserting a CheckBox from the developer tab. I want to have a 3-state CheckBox (checked, intermediate, and unchecked), but whenever I pull up the properties of the CheckBox, it only gives me the options for a 2-state CheckBox (checked and unchecked).

Is there anyway to insert a 3-state CheckBox in Microsoft Word? I'm comfortable with using VBA if needed.

Comment: In Access, this is allowed by marking off the "Triple State" property for the control. In Word, this doesn't seem to be an option. What is the problem that you are trying to solve with the control?

Comment: You can if you use an ActiveX checkbox. I found that object under the "legacy tools" menu on the developer tab with Word 2016. That's all I have access to at the moment. Do you have the ActiveX option?

Comment: @PatJones - I am building a form for my business to do insurance reviews. When my employees ask the insured about different lines of insurance, I want them to be able to have a check mark for if it insured with us, an x mark for if it is insured elsewhere, or blank if there is no need.

Comment: @MoondogsMaDawg - That does seem to have the triple state option, do you know if I'm able to change the tick mark like we're able to in the non-legacy version?

Comment: I think your only option would be to build a customized activex control. You can learn how to briefly do that [here at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa239763(v=vs.60).aspx). I don't see any relevant appearance capabilities within the standard properties.

Comment: For this need, I'd use an option group control as it's more transparent to the end users and less of pain to program. It's just my opinion, but triple state check boxes are easily misinterpreted when in the third state.

Comment: @PatJones Ditto. The biggest issue I see is defining these states into three categories may not stand up to the chaos of reality. Option groups are scalable in that way, if you decide to add supplemental states down the road you can add the new selection to the group instead of replacing objects and possibly needing to refactor code.

Comment: Do be aware that ActiveX controls are not supported on Macs. IMHO you'd do better to use a dropdown from which the desired option can be chosen. Note, too, that you shouldn't use formfields and content controls in the same document; they weren't deigned to work together and trying to use them that way can lead to inconsistent results.